# two click event from one tag using a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on an `aside` it's working fine but when I add `active` class on the `aside` then click again it's not working. Actually I want to toggle the arrow when I click on the `aside` in active mode.

```
<article class="headings">
    <p class="link">Link</p>
    <aside class="date">
        Date 
        <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
    </aside>
    <aside class="page-views">
        Pageviews 
        <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
    </aside>
    <aside class="comments"> 
         Comments 
        <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
    </aside>
    <aside class="flikes">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> 
        Likes 
        <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
    </aside>
    <aside class="fshares">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> 
        Shares 
        <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
    </aside>
    <aside class="fcomments">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> 
        Comments     
        <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
    </aside>
    <aside class="tweets">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> 
        Tweets 
        <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
    </aside>
    <aside class="pins">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> 
        Pins 
        <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
    </aside>
    <aside class="gpost">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
        Posts 
        <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
    </aside>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</article>
```

```js
$('.headings aside').click(function() {
    $('.headings aside').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active')
    $('.headings aside').children('span.fa-caret-up').removeClass('fa-caret-up').addClass('fa-caret-down');
    $(this).children('span').removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-up');
});

$('.headings aside.active').click(function() {
    $(this).children('span').removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-up');
});
```

Comment: You may want to look into `toggleClass`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do you need to create a dynamic/delegated click function:

```
$(document).on('.click','.headings aside',function() {
    $('.headings aside').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active')
    $('.headings aside').children('span.fa-caret-up').removeClass('fa-caret-up').addClass('fa-caret-down');
    $(this).children('span').removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-up');
});

$(document).on('.click','.headings aside.active', function() {
    $(this).children('span').removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-up');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reverse `fa-caret-down` `fa-caret-up` to suit your needs

```
$('.headings aside').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("active")
   $(this).children('span').toggleClass('fa-caret-down fa-caret-up');
});
```